# How to format a DatePicker in WinUI 3 to display date format as: day/month/year (dd/MMM/yyyy)?

Tags: c#, xaml, datepicker, winui-3

DatePicker currently shows as: month/day/year (MMM/dd/yyyy)

[image: DatePicker]

[image: DatePickerControls]

How do I make it show as: day/month/year (dd/MMM/year)

[image: DatePicker-ddMMMyyyy]

[image: DatePickerControls-ddMMMyyyy]

I've already tried setting CurrentCulture to "sr-Latn-RS"

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("sr-Latn-RS");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

and setting language and CalendarIdentifier in XAML

```
CalendarIdentifier="GregorianCalendar"
Language="sr-Latn-RS"
```

Both of those have done nothing.

Comment: Just change the package.appxmanifest to set `<Resource Language="sr-Latn-RS"/>` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/localize-winui3-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to configure the application's `package.appxmanifest` to set

```
<Resource Language="sr-Latn-RS"/>
```

as instructed in the official documentation [Localize your WinUI 3 app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/localize-winui3-app)

and the picker will update it's UI automatically:

[image]